# Adding missing values in Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I currently have a dictionary with a numerical index as keys. I know how much values I should have in total in the dictionary and would like to add the missing keys and a null value with those keys in the dictionary. To illustrate I included this example:

```
dictionary = {'0' : '101',
              '1' : '102',
              '2' : '100',
              '4' : '100.5',
              '6' : '103'}
```

I know that I have 8 values in my dictionary and so I would like to write a function that turns the above dictionary into:

```
dictionary = {'0' : '101',
              '1' : '102',
              '2' : '100',
              '3' : None,
              '4' : '100.5',
              '5' : None,
              '6' : '103',
              '7' : None}
```

Anyone that knows how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you decide what's missing; in your example you found that '5' and '7' were missing, but what about '8', etc.   You've got to refine your question to specify that the keys are always single (?) character strings that represent positive integers, and you want to find in all the gaps between those integers.

Comment: @MarkLavin, I know that the amount of values should be 8 and as it is a numerical index, the index numbers should go from 0 to 7, which is how I determine which values are missing.

Comment: You say you have a numerical keys, but your shown keys are all *strings*. Which is it really?

Comment: The API returned the numerical index in string format, I wrote a function to undo it. You can therefore say it was both ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `N` is the number of items

```py
{**dictionary, **{k: None for k in range(N + 1) if str(k) not in dictionary.keys()}}
```

However, it might be better to have integers as keys in `dictionary`, in this way you do not have to cast to `str`

**Edit**
Thanks to schwobaseggl comment a better version is

```py
{**{str(k): None for k in range(N + 1)}, **dictionary}
```

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987/8227062) question about `dict` merge in `python`

Comment: No need for the `.keys()` when checking dict membership + missing one `str` cast. You could even be less verbose: `{**{str(k): None for k in range(N+1)}, **dictionary}`

Comment: @schwobaseggl Or `{}.fromkeys(map(str, range(N+1))) | dictionary`.

Comment: @KellyBundy Raises a `TypeError` for me... (Python 3.8)

Comment: @schwobaseggl Then update your Python already :-P

Answer (score 1):

The following would do the trick:

```
m = max(map(int, dictionary))
for i in map(str, range(m)):
    if i not in dictionary: 
        dictionary[i] = None
```

But whether that is necessary is questionable as you could easily provide the default upon lookup: `dictionary.get(key)` will return `None` anyway for missing keys.

Comment: Or `for i in range(m): dictionary.setdefault(str(i))`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
dictionary = {'0' : '101', '1' : '102', '2' : '100', '4' : '100.5', '6' : '103'}
key_list = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
for k in key_list:
    try:
        dictionary[k]
    except KeyError:
        dictionary[k] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, if you know that your values are following each other, you can use the following function:

```
def complete_dict(my_dict, begin_at=0, stops_at=8):
    for key in range(begin_at, stops_at):
        if str(key) not in my_dict.keys():
            my_dict[str(key)] = None
    return my_dict
```

It goes then from `begin_at` to `stops_at - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

So, since you know that it starts with 0 and goes to some value, you can use range to loop through all the items. If it already exists, just use the same value, and if it doesn't, add None.

```
d = {'0' : '101', '1' : '102', '2' : '100', '4' : '100.5', '6' : '103'}

for i in range(0, 7):
    d[str(i)] = d.get(str(i), None) 

d = dict(sorted(d.items()))
print(d)
```

Alternatively, instead of using same dictionary and doing sort by key, you could create new dictionary, which will automatically be sorted, since you're adding them in order.

This is if you're using keys as strings (like in your example). If they are int, just lose the `str(i)` and use just `i`

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `if k not in dictionary: dictionary[k] = None`?  Or to be fancy `dictionary[k] = dictionary.get(k)`

You can fill the `None`s if they are not present in the dictionary:

```
dictionary = {'0' : '101', '1' : '102', '2' : '100', '4' : '100.5', '6' : '103'}
keys = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
for k in keys:
    if k not in dictionary:
        dictionary[k] = None
```

Or if you want to be fancy:

```
dictionary = {'0' : '101', '1' : '102', '2' : '100', '4' : '100.5', '6' : '103'}
keys = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
for k in keys:
    dictionary[k] = dictionary.get(k)
```

`dictionary.get(k)` will return the value by key `k` or `None` if the value isn't in the `dictinary`.

Answer (score 0):

The above examples work fine for filling Nones, but you should consider, maybe in the place where you're retrieving values from the dict, using `dictionary.get(key, None)` instead of `dictionary[key]`. This way you'll get None for nonexistent keys, and have your original dictionary.